# is it possible for Wordpress Site to loading from 2 servers?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, vps

I have a WordPress platform based site, switched 3 hosting companies in 3 months, due to speed and uptime problem.
is it possible to host my site on two servers, if one is down site automatically run from second one :)

Note : 1). it  is a design images based site (you can say wallpaper site)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible you can host your site on multiple servers with one domain by providing different 'Name Servers' e.g. **ns1.domainname.com**, **ns2.domainname.com**, **ns1.diffdomainname.com** and so on in your website hosting panel. This will serve your issue if your site is down from one server, it easily picks the site from other server.

Comment: what about the changes which i will make on daily basis ?, as it is on wordpress platform and i regularly posting new articles my site.

Comment: well unfortunately you have to update it in all the servers where you have uploaded the wordpress site

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this problem is setting up high available and auto scalable infrastructure.
You can use AWS, it supports everything you need.

Your WordPress application can be have 3 layers.

1) Load balancing Layer

2) PHP Application Layer

3) Data Base Layer

You can use [elasticbeanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) to easily installation and maintenance of Load balancing Layer i.e ELB and PHP Application Layer i.e ec2 servers

check out this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html) for php application deployment using beanstack

make sure you are using multiple AZ(Availability Zone)s for in all layers to achieve high availability.

You can also use AWS RDS mysql or Aurora for DB layer

Answer (score 0):

Yes! This technology is called "**Load Balancing**" for Servers, you could configure your servers with open source software, or you can do it with comercial companies that offers this.

You should do **Load Balancing** for each service that you need like: MySQL (or your database system) and Apache (or your webserver).

He an example: [Setting Up A High-Availability Load Balancer (With Failover and Session Support) With HAProxy/Heartbeat On Debian Etch](http://www.howtoforge.com/high-availability-load-balancer-haproxy-heartbeat-debian-etch)